# Cannot create table in mysql

Tags: database-design

I want to create table which is having 216 fields but when I am trying to create it I got below error in mysql.

```
#1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

I don't know what is its solution.
please help me out.

Comment: Can you change the columns to smaller types?

Comment: No I cant change columns to smaller types.what shuould I do?any other option?

Comment: In that case you'll need to split it up as suggested in the answers

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE sql..?

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html "Although InnoDB supports row sizes larger than 65535 internally, you cannot define a row containing VARBINARY or VARCHAR columns with a combined size larger than 65535: " so it sounds like there could be a workaround. [Although I agree with the others who say that you really need to review your design]

Comment: @DilbertDave, yes there might be a workaround, but if you work around this, you are starting a 'workaround cycle' you soon will regret :-)

Comment: @Peter - agreed, but sometimes needs must ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is exact what mysql is telling you : you have too much data for one table. 
Not only the number of fields are counting towards them, but also their size..

But **the real problem** is in your database design, you have designed a table that is crying out for help : 'split me up, split me up!'

You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your design ..

Answer (score 1):

Row size too large. It means just that. Do you really need all those 216 fields? Can you cut them down?

If you really need those 216 fields, consider breaking them into 2-3 tables with 1:1 mapping from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear.  Add up the size of all your 216 fields and you should see that it exceeds the maximum.  As @Peter said you really need to re-think your design.  I table should have more than a few dozens fields maximum!

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing the field sizes or make text / blobs of them instead.

Show us the create table command you are trying to run.